# How to fix "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when using shared memory in Linux

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, shared-memory, coredump

I wrote a simple c program using shared memory in Linux (without multiple processes), after i got the "Segmentation error" in my full program.

I still get the same error. What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

void sys_err(char s[])
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid, *shmptr, *ptr;

    if(shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (10)*sizeof(int), 0666|IPC_CREAT)<0)
        sys_err("Cannot shmget");

    if((shmptr=(int*)shmat(shmid,0,0))<(int*)0)
        sys_err("Cannot shmat");

    shmptr[0]=1;    // <----- error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
    //OR
    *shmptr=1;  // <----- error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
    //OR
    ptr=shmptr; // <----- error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
    *ptr=1;

    if(shmdt(shmptr)<0)
        sys_err("Cannot shmdt");

    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know it it's the problem, but it is *a* problem: When you compare the result of `shmat` as `< (int *) 0` you are invoking *implementation specific* behavior, which may or may not work. Instead compare for equality with `-1` (i.e. `== (int *) -1`).

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment, pointers are themselves really just *unsigned* integers. I don't know what the C specification says about it, but checking if a pointer is less than zero is not an operation I would consider to be valid (as pointers by definition can't be negative). The direct equality comparison with `-1` (casted to a pointer) is all good an fine though.

Comment: Compile with warnings and everything will be clear. `shmid = shmget(...)<0` does not do what you think it does. And checking the return value with '<' is a bad idea too.

Comment: i tried. it dosn't work. thank you!

Comment: Please think about all possible cases where `shmptr` can be less than 0. There are: 0. You're not checking that error properly.

Answer (score 3):

i finaly found the problem.
is was actually small.

in this part:

```
if(shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (10)*sizeof(int), 0666|IPC_CREAT)<0)
    sys_err("Cannot shmget");
```

there are "()" missing to surround the hole expression like this:

```
if((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (10)*sizeof(int), 0666|IPC_CREAT))<0)
    sys_err("Cannot shmget");
```

now it runs.
thanks!